# What is the format of this timestamp? 2015-02-25T15:03:57+0000

Tags: java, datetime

I tried this:

```
"dd-MM-yy'T':HH:mm:SSZ"
```

But Im getting

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2015-02-25T15:06:38+0000" (at offset 11)
```

This is my code:

```
  SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(Preferences.SERVER_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT);
        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = format.parse(serverTimestamp);
            return date.getTime();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: Try flipping round the order of the year and day tokens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"`:

- Put the year first
- Remove the colon after the `T`
- Use seconds instead of milliseconds.

Comment: This is the right answer :) Will accept in a few minutes

Answer (score 1):

**2015-02-25T15:03:57+0000**

2015 **YYYY** - Year

02 **MM** - Month

25 **dd** - Day

T - just string with length 1

15 **HH** - Hours

03 **mm** - Minutes

57 **ss** - Seconds

+0000 **Z** - Time zone

so you need:

*"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:SSSZ"*

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html